# improper redirection mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to mvc.

I am developing web app using mvc4 mobile template.

I have controller say :

> **controller1**

and 
       actions of both type

> (get,post) : action1, action2, action3

Now, suppose my current URL : **http://localhost:12345/controller1/action1**
and I clicked on button to call its post action, code executes correctly

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ActionName("action1")]
 public ActionResult action1_post()
 {
     //some code here
     return RedirectToAction("action2","controller2");
 }
```

But in browser, still it shows this URL : **http://localhost:12345/controller1/action1**

I can't understand this..

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change ActionName into something else. This is the reason why it still shows as **action1** in url. If you change it to **action1post** then it should change. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("action1post")]
 public ActionResult action1_post()
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but if i change my post action signature like `public ActionResult action1(guid id){ ... }` and inside this action, it put code to redirect to **/controller2/action2**... still it will show the same URL in browser address bar... **http://localhost:12345/controller1/action1**

Comment: Do you have both controller2 and action2? And if you have are you sure that you don't return View somewhere before that this would cause it stay on the same view. Otherwise, if I try `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` I always get redirected to this action.

Comment: ya sure .. I have debugged the code many times.. control reaches to **return RedirectToAction(..)** statement

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353748/redirecttoaction-doesnot-change-the-browser-url) will answer it. If action requires certain attributes or it could be an issue with call to httppost action :)

Comment: i have also tried that 1.. still not solved...while redirecting from post action, this problem occurs..

Comment: my problem has been solved.. actually BY DEFAULT in jquerymobile, all the form submission are handled by ajax-call..