# RedirectToAction doesnot change the browser URL

Tags: jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to redirect from the Account controller (Account/Login)  to User/Index by doing below syntax.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
```

it shows up the correct view but the URL still persist as Account/Login. Can anyone suggest how can i achieve the same. I have tried some of the searches from google but none of them works for me.

Comment: Will handling an event and addiing window.location.href('url') work for you?

Comment: Are you calling this controller action with AJAX? Because if this is the case it is not surprising that the browser address bar doesn't change - that's the whole point of AJAX.

Comment: I am using @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "User", FormMethod.Post)) has input type submit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's an issue caused by jQuery-mobile. By default, jQM will make forms use ajax calls, as this is how page navigation is performed in the framework. [AJAX navigation is explained in more detail here.](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navigation/)

The solution is to add `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag used for the initial server call.

So your form would look like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
```

Comment: I want to do it in on of my controller not in the view.

Comment: Yes but the problem is due to using jQuery mobile in the view, there is nothing wrong with your controller's code. Therefore the view is what needs to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am using @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) to check my custom logic for login. I verify the user credential from Account/Login and if it is correct i need to redirect to User/Index.

Comment: In that case, since the login form is the one initiating the server call, that is the one which would need the `data-ajax="false"` attribute. I have  corrected the code in my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Not changed. It is redirecting to User/Index but still the url persist as Account/Login. For redirecting i am using return RedirectToRoute("User"); which i have "User" route mentioned in my application.

Comment: Ah, my apologies then, I thought that would have fixed the issue.

Comment: Huge +1 as I was stuck on this exact issue. Can anyone explain why an ajax call would not allow the redirect?

Comment: Well the purpose of AJAX is to make server calls without navigating to another page. jQM uses this, however, in order to make page transitions more seamless. You can read about what they do [here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/navigation/).

Comment: I have the same problem in a link button and this resolves the problem thanks!!
<a href="blabla.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-theme="e" data-ajax="false">