# passing data(Id) with redircetToAction to url using ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

hello I'm trying to pass the new posted value to a different view with the new value id at the url using RedirectToAction but I'm getting the wrong Url .
Just like here in SO ,that you get redirect to your Q. after submit.
the Url I'm suppose to get is  http://localhost:1914/en/evntes/index/60

MyCode(Controler= VoosUp)

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new LectureFormViewModel
        {
            Genres = _context.Genres.ToList(),

        };
        return View("Gigform", viewModel);
    }

    [Authorize, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(LectureFormViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();

            return View("Gigform", viewModel);
        }


        var lectureGig = new LectureGig
        {
             //Prametrest
        };

        _context.LectureGigs.Add(lectureGig);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        // return this.RedirectToAction( "events", (c=>c.Index(lectureGig.Id)); //Compiler Error
        return RedirectToAction("index", "Events", new { id = lectureGig.Id });//Ok Id 60
    }
```

Events/Index

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)//OK id=60
    {
        var lecturegig = _context.LectureGigs.Include(g => g.Artist)
           .Include(g => g.Genre)
           .SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
        if (lecturegig == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        var viewmodel = new GigDetailViewModel { LectureGig = lecturegig };


        return View("index", viewmodel);
    }
```

Url i'm getting :http://localhost:1914/en/VoosUp/Create
and the view is correct

Comment: what and where ur getting problem

Comment: the url is  incorrect http://localhost:1914/en/VoosUp/Create instead of http://localhost:1914/en/evntes/index/60 while the view is correct .

Comment: Are you posting using AJAX? If yes, take a look at this answer [RedirectToAction does not change the browser URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353748/redirecttoaction-doesnot-change-the-browser-url).

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider ,I have remove the ajax posting and  that's true without the ajax post it's working , but data_ajax ="false" , is not changing it .and I do need  to post ajax .

Comment: Maybe this technique works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7929108/1450855

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider It doesn't look like it can help but this one look promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call/1534662#1534662  , im just not sure how to use it in my case